# Elm what is "x" in a type signature?

Tags: elm

Trying to figure out how to get the current time, and I found the method, but don't know how to read the type signature.

The signature is `now : Task x Time` you can see it [here](https://github.com/elm-lang/core/blob/3833b53f57f21df7ce7d3cf6664c61ee5671df4b/src/Time.elm#L42-L46).

Can't figure out how to search for it since they use `x` as a variable name everywhere, I can generally find the rightish place within the parser code, but have a lot of difficulty following it.

Answer (score 5):

The type `x` is a so called `type parameter`. This means that the type is not defined yet.

In your particular case, the definition of the type [`Task`](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/4.0.1/Task#Task), the first type after `Task` denotes the type with which your asynchronous operation may fail.

At the moment of the definition of the function this type is not fully defined. You have the freedom, in your program, to use as error type the type you want

Answer (score 3):

The definition:

```
now : Task x Time
```

means (loosely translated):

> Time.now is a Task which, when executed, will give you either:
>
> - output of type `x` if it fails,
> - output of type `Time` if it succeeds.

Since the Task `Time.now` can never fail, it doesn't matter what the error type is.
In Elm, lowercase types (`a`, `b`, `x`, `comparable`, `msg`) mean that the type could be anything, i.e. the function would work with different types.

- `msg` for message types.
- `comparable` means that it needs to be a type where you can compare
  two values (e.g. if the function does comparison between to values of
  that type, to determine which one is larger etc).

This makes sense for input types. But less so for output. I guess in this case the `x` means more or less "not applicable". A `Task` type needs an error output type. But in this case, it is irrelevant.

Addendum: To actually **get** the current time, you would need to take two more steps:

1. Performing the task, which returns a `Cmd`:
   `timeCmd = Task.perform identity MyMsg Time.now`
   This will perform the time-task, and wrap the resulting time in a `Cmd MyMsg`
2. Handle the `Cmd` output: for this, you would need to include a `MyMsg` handler in your `update` function.